# What is the possessive form of blocked?

Tags: possessives, saxon-genitive

What is the possessive form of blocked when used as a verb. For example:

> Remove the friend I blocked’s material.

Comment: What you have is fine — just like the Queen of England’s hat. The clitic applies to the entire noun phrase, not to the head noun.

Comment: It's technically OK but sounds sucky.  School of Rock has the right idea.

Comment: In case the crux of tchrist’s point was not clear: _blocked_ is the past tense of the verb _block_ in your sentence here, and verbal forms do not have possessive forms. Possession (also called the genitive) is a notion that does not apply to verbs, only to nominal elements (basically nouns and adjectives, but in English most particularly _noun phrases_). The possessive in your sentence does not apply to _blocked_, but to the entire noun phrase _the friend I blocked_.

Comment: The terms 'grammatical' and 'fine' seem not to overlap precisely.

Comment: Only a noun can have a genitive-s. You can't add a genitive-s to verbs  or other word classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write, "Remove the material of the friend I blocked."

Comment: This answer doesn't actually address OP's question. It's just (related) *writing advice*, which would have been better posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a stylistic problem, as the reader needs to recognize instantly that you are using 'friend-I-blocked' as a phrase. It's not strictly comparable to 'Queen of England', where there is a noun at the beginning and end of the phrase and where the phrase is in any case well established.